# How to avoid flashing when switching between 2 compoents ? When using firebase auth

Tags: reactjs

Tried what i could but i failed ,tried with useState and all but nope.

Im using firebase auth ,if the user is logged in I show main page component ,if not i show the log in page ,but sometimes it just flashes the login page and goes to the main page in a weird/bad way ,any suggestions to fix it?

EDIT : I tried without useEffect but still the same

```js
function App() {
    const [mycurrentUser,SetCurrentUser] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        onAuthStateChanged(auth,  (user) => {
            if (user) {
                SetCurrentUser(user)
            } else {
                SetCurrentUser(null)
            }

        });

    }, [auth.currentUser])

    return (
        <section>
            { mycurrentUser
                ? <FeedPage/>
                : <AuthPage/>}
        </section>

    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One thing i noticed is that you don't have to keep calling the `onAuthStateChange`, just once on mount is good enough.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        onAuthStateChanged(auth,  (user) => {
            if (user) {
                SetCurrentUser(user)
            } else {
                SetCurrentUser(null)
            }
        });
    }, [])
```

Also how does the `Auth` page know the current user ? Either you have to pass it in via prop or context.

Comment: It will still flash nonetheless ,when i refresh the page the user changes from null to an object quickly causing a flash between renders , Auth page does not need to know the user It's just used to create an account or login ,im confused on what to do.